# How can I persist local Javascript data on a page with postbacks, but clear it when the user navigates away?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session-storage

I have a control in a large ASP.NET application. The control uses AJAX to communicate with the server, and stores a very large amount of state locally. All of the pages consuming this control make excessive use of ASP.NET post backs.

I need to persist the control's state across post backs, but I need the state to be wiped out when the user navigates away from the page, either by browsing to another location or performing a post back that redirects. I cannot send this state to the server and echo it back.

Currently, I'm using `sessionStorage`, but it doesn't satisfy the requirement that the state be wiped out if the user navigates away from the page.

As a caveat, I have zero control over the consumers of the control.

How can I accomplish this? Is this even possible?

Comment: Have you tried ViewState?? It works like Session variables, but ViewState variables just live in one page, when the user change the page, they are dropped

Comment: Take a look to the event onbeforeunload (That if i don't remember bad is executed before the user leave or close the page). So you can clean your local stored data (sessionStorage or other) when that event occur.

Comment: @EnriqueZavaleta: That doesn't satisfy my requirement that the state can't be sent to the server. This state can be up to 4 MB.

Comment: @ecarrizo: OnBeforeUnload occurs on postback.

Comment: How do you know when a postback will cause a redirect? If you can determine the actions that cause a redirect, catch them before the postback and clear the data before it's sent.

Comment: @MichaelTodd: I don't know when a post back will cause a redirect, which is the problem. I have no control over what the page is doing outside of this control.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee see my answer. This will probably solve your ViewState validation problem as well since the UpdatePanel is designed to complement standard WebForms behavior, not replace it with a new mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't generally recommend this, but the following may actually be the best option for you since you are working within strict confines of the standard WebForms paradigm.

You can [implement IScriptControl on your control and add AJAX functionality using Microsoft Ajax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386450%28v=vs.140%29.aspx), or alternatively [create an extender that extends your control with AJAX capabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386403%28v=vs.140%29.aspx).

You'll want to use this in conjunction with an UpdatePanel so the control can still post back as usual and the ViewState mechanism remains intact, but the postback becomes an asynchronous communication with the server. Any control data, ViewState or otherwise, is local to the control/page, meeting your requirement that the data is cleared when you navigate away.